node.js code snippet not working in vscode
Recently, when I work with VSCode for Node.js and Express, it doesn't suggest any code snippet. How can I fix the suggestion problem? It provides code suggestions for JavaScript, but not for Node and Express.
I've tried both CommonJS and moduleJS, and I've installed almost all the related extensions in VSCode. There wasn't an issue before, but now the code snippet isn't working.

Please see [ask]. Your post needs improvement. Also take the [tour].

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can try to install these packages for development mode: npm install @types/node @types/express --save-dev
